# Facebook ReasonでCoreライブラリをリンクしたい

Tags: facebook, ocaml, reason

OCaml 4.02.3, Reason 0.0.5, OS X 10.11.5 です。

Reasonのコードは以下です。

```
open Core.Std;
printf "test %f" (Float.of_int 3);
```

コンパイルします。

```
$ rebuild -pkgs core a.native
```

エラーになってバイナリが生成されません。
何かオプションフラグを追加指定してやれば、a.nativeの生成まで出来るのではないかと思いますが、
わかる方がいたら教えていただきたいです。

> Error: No implementations provided for the following modules:
>             Thread referenced from > > /Users/ow/.opam/4.02.3/lib/core/core.cmxa(Core)
>            Mutex referenced from /Users/ow/.opam/4.02.3/lib/core/core.cmxa(Core)
>            Condition referenced from /Users/ow/.opam/4.02.3/lib/core/core.cmxa(Core)
>            Event referenced from /Users/ow/.opam/4.02.3/lib/core/core.cmxa(Core)
>   Command exited with code 2.
>   Hint: Recursive traversal of subdirectories was not enabled for this build,
>     as the working directory does not look like an ocamlbuild project (no
>     '_tags' or 'myocamlbuild.ml' file). If you have modules in subdirectories,
>     you should add the option "-r" or create an empty '_tags' file.
>
> To enable recursive traversal for some subdirectories only, you can use the
>     following '_tags' file:
>
> ```
>  true: -traverse
>   <dir1> or <dir2>: traverse
> ```
>
> Compilation unsuccessful after building 4 targets (3 cached) in 00:00:00.

一方、同じプログラムをOCamlで書き直すと多分こんな風だと思います。

```
open Core.Std;;
let () = printf "test %f" (Float.of_int 3);;
```

コンパイルします。

```
$ corebuild -verbose 1 a.native
```

ビルドは成功し実行可能なa.nativeができました。

そこで、a.cmxを作るところまでは、rebuildコマンドでも出来ているみたいなので、

```
$ rebuild -pkgs core a.native
```

が失敗した後に、corebuildコマンドを真似て以下のコマンドを手入力するとa.nativeを作成できました。

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlopt -linkpkg -g -thread -package core _build/a.cmx -o  a.native
```

ですから、以下のコマンドに何かフラグを追加してやればうまくいくのではないか、と思ったのですが何かアイデアありますでしょうか。

```
$ rebuild -pkgs core a.native
```

Comment: ネイティブバイナリの作成ではなく、バイトコードの作成であれば、
次のように、オプションを追加することで実行形式を作成できました。
`rebuild -use-ocamlfind -tag thread -pkgs core a.byte`

Real World OCamlをReasonの文法で勉強する目的には、これで十分そうです。
ネイティブバイナリをエラーなく作成する方法は引き続きお待ちしてます。

Comment: Reason の人に聞くのが一番早いと思います。

Comment: 本家でも同じような質問がありました: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37504534/how-to-use-jane-streets-core-with-reason

Answer (score 1):

Reasonのgithubに質問と回答がありました。

https://github.com/facebook/reason/issues/556

それを参考に、以下のようにしてコマンド一発でエラーなくネイティブバイナリを作成できました。

```
$ ocamlfind ocamlc -g -thread -package core -pp refmt -linkpkg -o a.native -impl a.re
```